# Ubuntu 16.04 - Docker installed but not available

Tags: docker, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, apt

I am trying to install `docker` on an Ubuntu-16.04 server.
When I execute `sudo apt-get install -y docker-ce` the system tells me that docker is already installed:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y docker-ce
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
docker-ce is already the newest version (5:19.03.1~3-0~ubuntu-xenial).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 133 not upgraded.
```

And running `sudo systemctl status docker` looks like it's already running:

```
$ sudo systemctl status docker
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor     preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2019-08-21 17:26:02 PDT; 24min ago
     Docs: http://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 14283 (dockerd)
    Tasks: 28
   Memory: 64.7M
      CPU: 1.128s
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
       └─14283 /usr/bin/dockerd

Aug 21 17:26:02 node1 dockerd[14283]: time="2019-08-21T17:26:02.137366865-07:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period"
Aug 21 17:26:02 node1 dockerd[14283]: time="2019-08-21T17:26:02.137381329-07:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime"
Aug 21 17:26:02 node1 dockerd[14283]: time="2019-08-21T17:26:02.139558576-07:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Aug 21 17:26:02 node1 dockerd[14283]: time="2019-08-21T17:26:02.229011852-07:00" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address"
Aug 21 17:26:02 node1 dockerd[14283]: time="2019-08-21T17:26:02.264094521-07:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
Aug 21 17:26:02 node1 dockerd[14283]: time="2019-08-21T17:26:02.317824839-07:00" level=warning msg="Not using native diff for overlay2, this may cause degraded performance for building images: opaque flag erroneously copied up, consider u
Aug 21 17:26:02 node1 dockerd[14283]: time="2019-08-21T17:26:02.318092298-07:00" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=74b1e89e8a graphdriver(s)=overlay2 version=19.03.1
Aug 21 17:26:02 node1 dockerd[14283]: time="2019-08-21T17:26:02.318144708-07:00" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
Aug 21 17:26:02 node1 dockerd[14283]: time="2019-08-21T17:26:02.333727950-07:00" level=info msg="API listen on /var/run/docker.sock"
Aug 21 17:26:02 node1 systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
```

But when I try to run `docker-ps` I get this error:

```
$ docker ps
The program 'docker' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install docker.io
```

Also `which docker` doesn't return anything...

Any idea of what can be going on here? How can I debug this further?

Thanks in advance

### UPDATE

`docker-cli` appears to be installed to:

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce-cli
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
docker-ce-cli is already the newest version (5:19.03.1~3-0~ubuntu-xenial).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 133 not upgraded.
cord@node1:~$ which docker
```

But still the `docker` command is not there.

Here is the output of `dpkg -L docker-ce`:

```
$ dpkg -L docker-ce
/.
/etc
/etc/default
/etc/default/docker
/etc/init.d
/etc/init.d/docker
/etc/init
/etc/init/docker.conf
/lib
/lib/systemd
/lib/systemd/system
/lib/systemd/system/docker.socket
/lib/systemd/system/docker.service
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/dockerd
/usr/bin/docker-init
/usr/bin/docker-proxy
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/docker-ce
/usr/share/doc/docker-ce/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/docker-ce/README.md
/var
/var/lib
/var/lib/docker-engine
/var/lib/docker-engine/distribution_based_engine.json
```

Comment: `dpkg -L docker-ce` could see `docker` command?

Comment: updated the qeustion with the output, I can't see the `docker` command in `/usr/bin`

Answer (score 1):

I guess the install of your docker not complete for some reason or your steps not correct not sure.

What I suggest is next:

**Step1: Remove the old install**

```
$ apt-get purge docker-ce
```

**Step2: Install docker [using convenience script](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#upgrade-docker-engine---community-1)**

```
$ curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh
$ sudo sh get-docker.sh
```

If above still can not work, you can just use a prebuilt binary for docker client, see [this](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/binaries/#install-static-binaries):

1. Downloads your neede version from https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/x86_64/
2. Untar the downloaded package to get the docker binary, `tar xzvf /path/to/<FILE>.tar.gz`
3. Copy one binary with the name `docker` to `/usr/bin`, something like `sudo cp docker/docker /usr/bin/`

With above you have docker client ready in your system.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the `docker-ce-cli` package. The `docker-ce` package only contains the daemon.

```
$ dpkg -L docker-ce
...
/usr/bin/dockerd
/usr/bin/docker-init
/usr/bin/docker-proxy
...
```

The [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/) for installation on Ubuntu does not mention this directly, but the installation step includes `docker-ce-cli`:

> `sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io`

Comment: Same thing happens with the CLI, apparently is already installed